# Using Guava for high performance thread-safe caching

Tags: caching, guava

I am trying to implement a high performance thread-safe caching. Here is the code I have implemented. I don't want any on demand computing. Can I use cache.asMap() and retrieve the value safely? Even if the cache is set to have softValues?

```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
  import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

  import com.google.common.cache.Cache;
  import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;

  public class MemoryCache {

    private static MemoryCache instance;
    private Cache<String, Object> cache;

    private MemoryCache(int concurrencyLevel, int expiration, int size) throws IOException {

        cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().concurrencyLevel(concurrencyLevel).maximumSize(size).softValues()
            .expireAfterWrite(expiration, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    }

    static public synchronized MemoryCache getInstance() throws IOException {
        if (instance == null) {
               instance = new MemoryCache(10000, 3600,1000000);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Object get(String key) {
        ConcurrentMap<String,Object> map =cache.asMap();
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public void put(String key, Object obj) {
        cache.put(key, obj);
    }
   }
```

Comment: As a curiosity, do you really expect to have 10000 threads accessing your Cache concurrently? I ask since that's the value you're using as a concurrency level.

Comment: No I've removed that parameter. I am now using the default concurrency level i.e. 4. Thanks for point it out though.

Answer (score 32):

Guava contributor here:

Yes, that looks just fine, although I'm not sure what the point is of wrapping the cache in another object.  (Also, `Cache.getIfPresent(key)` is fully equivalent to `Cache.asMap().get(key)`.)

Answer (score 8):

If you want high performance, why don't you instanciate the Cache statically instead of using a synchronized getInstance()?

Comment: Agree. Using this idiom would remedy synchronization on getInstance(): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom

Comment: If you do that, I am not sure if it will have this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934913/are-static-variables-shared-between-threads

Comment: @SurasinTancharoen not if you instanciate it during the object initialization (either in the `MemoryCache` directly, or using the holder pattern, making it `final`). The question you linked to talks about shared state visibility and unsynchronized reads and writes.