# How to refactor a synchronization block based on string

Tags: java, refactoring

I am refactoring a legacy project and I have found a code that uses `String` for synchronization (Actually it's a Cache implementation).

```
public void method (String key, ...) {

 synchronized(key) {
   ....
  }
}
```

There is only one block which synchronize on String object `key`.

I am wondering which is the best way for fixing/Refactoring the code?

Any ideas?

Comment: The first thing to do is to clarify whether there are other `synchronized` blocks, supposed to synchronize on the same object.

Comment: @Holger updated the question

Comment: Have a look at [Synchronizing on an ID](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.fi/2008/04/java-synchronizing-on-transient-id.html).

Comment: @MickMnemonic the implementation adds a synchronization level to get the lock. Isn't that heavy?

Comment: Might be; it really depends on your application. If you want high throughput, consider using a [Guava Cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained). An example implementation is given in [Using Guava for high performance thread-safe caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124856/using-guava-for-high-performance-thread-safe-caching).

Comment: Yeah it's sure that's a better option in the mean I have to live the old fat code

Comment: You have not described any problem. All you have described are facts. Why do you want to rewrite this code? What are the perceived problems? BTW what you want to do is NOT a refactoring. You want to rewrite.

Comment: @JnRouvignac I am ok it's not refactoring it's potential bug fix. Visit https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK01-J.+Do+not+synchronize+on+objects+that+may+be+reused

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133988/synchronizing-on-string-objects-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is the following pattern:

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> lockMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
public void method(String key, ...) {
    synchronized(getLock(key)) {
        ....
    }
}
protected Object getLock(String key) {
    Object newLock = new Object(), lock = lockMap.putIfAbsent(key, newLock);
    return lock == null? newLock: lock;
}
```

Note that this is a proven pattern as the parallel class loaders, introduced with Java 7, use it as well.

With Java 8, you can simplify the code:

```
protected Object getLock(String key) {
    return lockMap.computeIfAbsent(key, x->new Object());
}
```