# Java volatile keyword - why this code terminates

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I'm playing with volatile keyword in Java and I have this code that tries to show that a thread doesn't see changes introduced by another thread unless we declare data as volatile. I was expecting that the code below will never terminate as I haven't declared the shared data as volatile. Any ideas why this code actually terminates?

```
public class VolatileTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        var holder = new Holder();
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            for(int i = 0; i<100000; i++) {
                holder.counter++;
            }
        }).start();
        var t = new Thread(() -> {
            while(holder.counter < 10000) {
                System.out.println("Jestem w pętli");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(400);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
        t.join();
    }

    static class Holder {
        int counter = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you use the `volatile` keyword? BTW: Never write `catch (InterruptedException e) { }` exception should be handled, atleast logged

Comment: Threads are allowed to cache values of non-volatile variables. That's not a guarantee that they won't see changes.

Comment: This answer explain why your code "works" without the `volatile` keyword https://stackoverflow.com/a/30956634/5862990

Comment: This is why testing multi-threaded programs for correctness is a hard problem. The Java Language Specification guarantees that your program will behave a certain way if you obey certain rules. But, It does _NOT_ guarantee that your program will misbehave if you break the rules. Worst-case scenario is where you test the hell out of some software, it passes all of your tests, you ship it to an important client, and then the **** hits the fan six months later when they upgrade their OS. It happens. Don't ask me how I know!

Answer (score 0):

`Thread 1` MAY not see change from the `Thread 2` immediately if you don't use `volatile`, but eventually once in the future, that will happen when `Thread 2` empty CPU cache to main memory. In your example, if you use `volatile` on `counter` field, writing thread will always write to main memory when you call `holder.counter++` and reading thread will read from main memory every time you call `holder.counter < 10000`.