# Thread never stops in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading `Effective Java` and in *Chapter 10: Concurrency; Item 66: Synchronize access to shared mutable data*, there is some code like this:

```
public class StopThread {
private static boolean stopRequested;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(stopRequested);
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int i = 0;
            while (!stopRequested){
                i++;
            }

            System.out.println("done");
        }

    });
    backgroundThread.start();
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    stopRequested = true;
}

}
```

First, I think the thread should run one second and then stop, since the `stopRequested` is set to `true` afterwards. However, the program never stops. It will never print `done`. The author said

```
while (!stopRequested)
    i++;
```

will be transformed into this:

```
if (!stopRequested)
     while(true)
         i++;
```

Could someone explain me this?

And another thing I find is that if I change the program to this:

```
public class StopThread {
private static boolean stopRequested;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(stopRequested);
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int i = 0;
            while (!stopRequested){
                i++;
                System.out.println(i);
            }

            System.out.println("done");
        }

    });
    backgroundThread.start();
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    stopRequested = true;
}
```

}

The program runs 1 second and stops as expected. What's the difference here?

Comment: Actually in second code what difference you made? Cant see anything other than one println.

Comment: The first program never stopped. The second program will stopped in one sec. You can try it on your desktop.

Comment: @Aajan yeah, I also can only spot the additional println in the while loop.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934913/are-static-variables-shared-between-threads?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I doubt the author actually said that (exactly).

But the point is that

```
while (!stopRequested)
    i++;
```

*could* behave like

```
if (!stopRequested)
     while(true)
         i++;
```

since the Java spec allows the initial value of `stopRequested` to be cached in a register, or fetched from a (potentially stale) copy in the memory cache.  One thread is not guaranteed to read the results of memory writes made by another thread *unless* there is a formal "happens before" relationship between the write and the subsequent read.  In this case, there is no such relationship.  That means that it is not specified whether the child thread will see the result of the parent thread's assignment to `stopRequested`.

As the author of that book would have explained, the solutions include:

- declaring `stopRequested` as `volatile`,
- making sure that the code that reads and writes `stopRequested` does so within a `synchronized` blocks or methods that synchronizes on the same object,
- uses `Lock` objects rather than `synchronized`, or
- some other concurrency mechanism that satisfies the "happens before" requirement.

---

Then you ask why your test seemed to work.

That's is explained by the fact that while the child is not guaranteed to see the effect of the parent's assignment, it is also not guaranteed to NOT see it ... either.

Or to put it another way.  The Java spec does not say which of the two possibilities will happen.

Now for a specific program, compiled by a specific compiler, run by a specific version of the JVM on specific hardware, you *could* find that the program behaved one way (or the other way) consistently.  Maybe 99.9% of the time.  Maybe even 100% of the time.  But the same program compiled and run in a different context *could* behave differently.  The JLS says so.

---

Another explanation for why the two almost identical versions of the program behave differently is that the `System.out` `PrintWriter` object is doing some internal synchronization when `println` is called.  That could be giving you a serendipitous "happens before".

Comment: I agree with you if there is no `sleep` for one second. But doesn't this like ta listener? The child thread is keep listening the change made by the main thread and if it changes, it will do something else?

Comment: @byteBiter - Nope.  It is not required to check for changes if there is no "happens before".  That's what the JLS is saying.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are making Joshua Bloch (the author of that great book) say something that he did not say :-). To be precise, the book says the following (only emphasize mine):

In the absence of **synchronization**, it's quite **acceptable** for the virtual machine to transform this code:

```
while (!done)
  i++;
```

into this code:

```
if (!done)
  while (true)
    i++;
```

To understand what he means (it's rather tough to explain it in a way better than he has himself done in pages 261-264, but I will try. Sorry Josh!) you should first try to run this program verbatim and see what is happening. With multithreading, anything is possible, but here's what I did:

1. Coded up `StopThread` as is.
2. Ran it on my Linux computer with JRE 1.8.0_72.
3. It simply hung! So, the behavior has not changed from what he described.
4. Then I took the 'thread dump' to see what is happening. You can simply send a `kill -3` signal to the running JVM pid to see what the threads are doing. Here's what I observed (relevant portion of the thread dump):

> ```
> "DestroyJavaVM" #10 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd678009800 nid=0x1b35 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "Thread-0" #9 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd6780f6800 nid=0x1b43 runnable [0x00007fd64b5be000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>   at StopThread$1.run(StopThread.java:14)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> "Service Thread" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd6780c9000 nid=0x1b41 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
> ```

As you can see, the background thread that we started is alive, doing *something*. I looked at my computer's diagnosis tool named `top` and here is what it shows:

[image: top cmd output].

Can you see that one of my CPU's (it's a quad core computer) is fully busy (100%!) doing *something*, moreover, it is *the java* process that is doing *something*. Isn't it puzzling? Well it is somewhat puzzling. When a CPU is busily doing something you don't understand, one very likely cause is that it is tirelessly checking contents of some memory location. In this case, if you try to connect the dots, it's the *stopRequested* variable whose value (as we can expect) it is constantly reading. So, effectively, the CPU is just reading the value of the boolean, finding it false, all the time and it goes back to checking if it has changed! Again, it finds it has not (it is still hanging on my machine as I write this :-)).

You'll say ... Didn't the `main thread` (which, by the way, has long gone, since it does not appear in the thread dump) `stopRequested = true`?

Yes, it did!

Naturally, you would suspect then, why doesn't the `Thread-0` **see** it?

And therein lies the clue. In the presence of a data race, the value that a thread writes is not *visible* to another thread that reads it.

Now we look at the declaration of that data, that variable that shows this peculiar behavior:

```
private static boolean stopRequested;
```

is what it is! This particular declaration is rather underspecified as far as its treatment by **various** involved parties (the compiler, the just in time compiler and its optimizations ...) is concerned. In the case of such underspecification, anything may happen. In particular, the value that the main thread (thought it) wrote may never be actually written into the main memory for `Thread-0` to read, making it go into an infinite loop.

Thus, this is a visibility issue. Without **enough** synchronization, it is not guaranteed that the value written by a thread will be *seen* by another thread.

Does that explain? For more details, we all need to have a better understanding of modern hardware. An excellent resource for this is [The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123973376) by Herlihy and Shavit. This book makes a software engineer understand the intricacies of the hardware and also explains why the multithreading is so hard.

Comment: OK. Let's say `stopRequested` is just a pointer, it points to a piece of memory which stores the value. And at the very beginning, the value is false. Then main thread and another child thread start to run. Then main thread change the value of `stopRequested` to `true` after 1 second. Are you saying that the child thread is not reading the same piece of the memory?

Comment: It's somewhat strange that you infer "child thread is not reading the same piece of the memory" after the demo I provided. Let's put it this way: the main thread tries to write it to the same location that Thread-0 reads. It's just that the liberties that the various layers are allowed to take end up in that main thread's update not appear in the main memory (RAM). For instance, there is nothing requiring contents of the L1/L2/.. cache (that main thread wrote to) to be reflected in the RAM.