# How to correctly implement communication between Java classes

Tags: java, class

I'm a beginner in Java programming and I'm currently working on an app with more complex class structure and a GUI. This might be a stupid questions, but it is very hard to google, so I'm asking here.

I have a main class, looking like this:

```
package app;

public class App {
    private FirstClass fc;
    private SecondClass sc;

    public App () {
        fc = new FirstClass ();
        sc = new SecondClass ();

        // ... code continues ...
    }
}
```

Say the SecondClass is defined outside of this .java file (like GUI forms are). Is there a way for me to access the "fc" instance (or other member variables of the App instance) from the "sc" instance (without passing the "this" pointer)? Something like:

```
class SecondClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        getWhoeverCreatedThisInstance().fc.getSomeData();

        // ... code continues ...
    }
}
```

And if not, what am I doing wrong? Should I design this differently? Maybe setting the "fc" as static? But what if I want more of my app's classes to communicate with each other, should I make them all static? What would be the point of having something non-static then? I could pass the "this" pointer of "App" or "fc" instance in the constructor of "SecondClass", but that solution just seems non-elegant when the number of classes that need this behavior rises.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you be more specific with the question? like do you want to have only a single instance of `FirstClass`?

Comment: If you don't pass `App` (aka `this`) to the `SecondClass` constructor, how did you expect `getWhoeverCreatedThisInstance()` to work, given that `App` *is* the whoever-created-this-instance?

Comment: @Blip: yes, there will be only one instance necessary. Basically it's classes like GUI, database connector etc...

Comment: @Andreas: well I was wondering if Java offers some way to access the "creator" instance without the "this" pre workaround

Comment: @StanleyBarkwill It doesn't. And passing `this` is not a "workaround". That's how you do it.

Comment: Generally when creating a Swing GUI, you would use the [model / view / controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  Read my [Moving Eyes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981403/bufferedimage-not-being-cleared-before-each-rendering/35002727#35002727) answer for a simple GUI using the model / view / controller pattern.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to implement a callback system with interfaces. Each of your classes communicating with each other should implement these.
The classes should Register to the creating class.
Then they can call a method in the creating class which invokes the interface method of each registered class and passed the data this way.

This SO answer might help 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18279545

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop GUI applications, you should really get into the basic concepts. This can be very time-consuming, but it is necessary, otherwise you will encouter *strange* behaviour. I will just give you a basic understanding to answer your question.

You think of simple console applications, where you usually have a single thread and passing around objects is valid. With multiple threads, this is **fatal**, even with [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934913/are-static-variables-shared-between-threads) variables. Each variable or object can be modified **concurrently** and the other thread may not be able to 'see' the changes *in time*. This is a complex matter, since there are also caches and separate stacks for each thread. In short, `fc` may not always be synchronized in `App` and `sc`, therefore reads and writes may be inconsistent.

What to do now? Learn the concepts of GUI programming. Often you do not even have to share objects for simple things. If a GUI control triggers an action, use a `Listener`, look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html). If you want to access a database for example, then just make a new connection object for each request or button click, whatever. This is simple to start, add complexity later.

A simple variant to share objects is to use the `synchronized` keyword, which ensures that a method or a field is only accessed by one thread at a time. Here is an [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_communication.htm). Also look at thread-safe data structures provided by Java (java.util.concurrent).

For advanced purposes you would have a separate thread and you would connect them with **Sockets** to pass messages or data.